# Eloquent Model Macro with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, macros

I'm attempting to set hidden attributes on an Eloquent model depending on the role type. For example, the macro I've written below will adapt the models in a collection to hide the fields for the given role.

```
Collection::macro('roleRestrict', function () {
    switch (true) {
        case RoleChecker::isUserGuest():
            return $this->map(function (AuthorisedAttributeInterface $model) {
                $model->setGuestRoleHiddenFields();
                return $model;
            });
        default:
            return $this;
    }
});
```

Which can be used with `MyModel::all()->roleRestrict()`

**Is it possible to write a similar macro which applies to a single model object outside of a collection? This would be executed as follows:**

```
MyModel::findOrFail($id)->roleRestrict()
```

Or even if the model is eager loaded with a belongsTo relationship:

```
AnotherModel::with('myModelRelationship')->findOrFail($id)->roleRestrict()
```

Comment: If you want to use `MyModel::findOrFail($id)->roleRestrict()`, you will have to implement a public function inside your Model, won't you?

Comment: @NEXTLEVELSHIT that won't work with eager loading.

Comment: If you have got dependent relations, you could load them "lazy eagerly": https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

You will only have to declare which relations should be included for your tasks. Have you tried it already?

Comment: I can see where you're going, but I'd like to avoid this sort of role based business logic at the model level, I would prefer to extract it to a higher level, such as the Collection macro.

Comment: I recently wrote a little package to to just this... add methods to Eloquent models through macros: https://github.com/javoscript/laravel-macroable-models Check it out, and let me know if it was of any use! =)